# Linq: Select First Items from the Child List?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have the following one-to-many relation between two objects.

```
Parent
   --> IList<Child>
```

Now, I have a **List of Parent** objects and I want the **First Child** of each parent in the list.

What is the best way to do this using Linq?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
parents.Where(p => p.Children.Any()).Select(p => p.Children.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate each "Parent" and find the first of it's offspring:

```
parent.FirstOrDefault(child => parent.Children.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

parent.child.FirstOrDefault();